# In Pokemon, can I trade Gen 1 items to Gen 2?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, game-boy

I have Pokemon Red and I'm playing through it, but I plan to use the Master Balls (both from Red and Gold) on two of the three legendary dogs. Is this possible with just the two games or with both Pokemon Stadiums?

Comment: This question confuses me. The legendary dogs are not in the first generation of pokemon. Blue and Red only have the legendary birds..

Comment: @Timelord64 I think they want to trade the masterball to gold version

Comment: @Timelord64 Based on "Gen 2" in the title, the idea is about transferring the master ball from the current run of Red to his future run of Gold

Comment: I agree with TimeLord that the question on it's own makes little sense, but with the title it is a bit clearer. Either way, I would look into re-wording the question to make that a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work at all, as there is no way that I'm aware of to trade/transfer items in Gen 1 games, so your master ball from the Red run is stuck there. While I have heard there is some sort of item storage in Stadium 2, my understanding is that it is also tied to your trainer ID, meaning items stored in this way cannot be withdrawn by any savegame that did not deposit the item.

Comment: It makes me wonder if changing the Trainer ID on Gold/Silver to match the one on Red would allow this to work

Comment: @Robotnik wouldn't surprise me if that worked; As Trainer ID locking was also used in My Pokemon Ranch, and when my DS was stolen along with my copy of Diamond, I was able to 'rescue' all my stored pokemon by editing my trainer ID on an Acecard save, withdrawing, and then editing the trainer ID to match my new copy of Diamond, and re-depositing them all. Then my new Pokemon Diamond cartridge was able to withdraw them all.

Comment: That being said, I'm not exactly clear on how Stadium 2 works in this regard. If item 'storage' in Stadium 2 is achieved by having Pokemon hold items... it wouldn't work anyway, as you'd still need to have your Gen 1 Pokemon hold the item, which is impossible, because that mechanic was new to Gen 2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to trade items up to Gen 2 from generation 1. The ability for Pokemon to hold items was not introduced until gen 2, so there is no way to give an item to a Pokemon in gen 1 and then trade it up (however, some Pokemon that you caught in gen 1 and trade up to gen 2 will be carrying items by default, such as a certain berry).

Also, if you have an item held by a Pokemon in gen 2 and then trade it down to gen 1, I believe the item will be lost (even if you trade the pokemon back up to gen 2).

Comment: My recollection of using the time machine to send Pokemon between Gen 2 and 1 was that held items would either be automatically shunted to your backpack, or it would refuse to trade (The time machine was rather picky - it would also refuse to send pokemon that knew moves introduced in gen 2)